# Avoiding color in fill legend with geom_col and geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I avoid superfluous (i.e., unused) colors from appearing in my fill legend? For example, the following R snippet generates the chart shown below which contains:

1. A color legend item for the red colored 'foo' dots (GOOD)
2. A fill legend with items for the dark and grey fills (GOOD)
3. But in the above fill legend I also get black dots, which don't appear anywhere in the plot

How do I remove the dots from #3? I.e., I want the `factor(p)` legend to consist of dark and light grey squares with no dots inside them. Note that using `show.legend` didn't seem to help.

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(x = 1:10) |> 
  crossing(p = 1/2:3) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x, x^p, fill = factor(p))) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_point(aes(color = 'foo'), position = position_dodge(1)) +
  scale_fill_grey()
```

[image: a plot with bars and dots]

Comment: Try adding `guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA)))` to your ggplot code

Comment: Thanks: adding the `guide(...)` fixes it.