# When does a fill legend have a dot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why does the `fill` legend sometimes have a dot and sometimes not? For example, given

```
library(ggplot2) # ggplot2_3.4.2

data.frame(x = 1, y = 2) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = 'a')) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = .5) ->
  p
```

Why do the following two plots have no dot in the fill legend,

```
p # fill legend has no dot

p + geom_point(aes(color = 'b')) # fill legend has no dot
```

but the following plot does have a dot?

```
p + geom_point(aes(color = 'b', fill = 'a')) # fill legend HAS A DOT
```

Note: the difference between this question other similar questions (e.g., [Avoiding color in fill legend with geom_col and geom_point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77910423/avoiding-color-in-fill-legend-with-geom-col-and-geom-point)) is that this question about how `ggplot2` decides whether to place a dot (or a point) in a legend (as opposed to how to remove it).

#### Update

Please read [stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12993861/)'s [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77934829/239838). Below are some additional examples (based on what he wrote) which I found helpful.

If we start with

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = 1, y = 2)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = c('a', 'b'))) +
  geom_point(
    aes(
      color = c('x', 'y'),
      # fill = c('m', 'n') # (*)
    ), 
    shape = 'circle filled',
    size = 9,
    position = position_jitter(seed = 1)) + 
  # geom_point(aes(fill = 'p'), shape = 'diamond', size = 3) + # (**)
  # geom_point(aes(fill = 'q'), shape = 'plus', size = 4, color = 'white') + # (***)
  scale_color_brewer('COLOR', palette = 'Set1') +
  scale_fill_brewer('FILL', palette = 'Accent')
```

then we get
[image]
which should be as expected; namely two different `fill`s for the bars and hence two entries in the fill legend FILL, and two different ink colors for the circles (just large points) and hence two entries in the color legend COLOR.

If we uncomment `(*)` then we get
[image]
which adds two colors to FILL as expected since there are two new mapped values (namely 'm' and 'n'). What's interesting is that ggplot2 also adds the symbols that might be using the new fill colors to FILL. I believe that all the different graphical elements that might use a mapped fill are called "glyphs" so the legends superimposes *all* the glyphs (filled rectangle plus circle) in the legend. You can see the pattern continue by uncommenting `(**)` to get:
[image]
which new sports a FILL legend with colored squares, circles and diamonds in it. The extra fill color might be surprising but if you change the shape to `'diamond filled'` it makes more sense. One can keep going and uncomment `(***)` to get:
[image]
which also illustrates a glyph of a different color (*not mapped*) which also appears in FILL.

A final example of the mechanical superposition of all glyphs happens if you move the `geom_col` to after all the `geom_point`s:
[image]
where the points in both the plot and legend have become obscured by the rectangles from the `geom_col`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a dot in the `fill` legend because you map on the `fill` aesthetic in different geom's, i.e. you map on the `fill` aesthetic both in `geom_col` and in `geom_point`.

A legend reflects the scale or the range of values of the variable mapped an aesthetic, whereas the key glyph aka the symbol used in the legend reflects the `geom`, i.e. for a `geom_col` you will get a rectangle, for a `geom_point` you will get a "dot".

And if you map on the same aesthetic in different geoms, both or all key glyphs are displayed in the legend.

- In your first plot you map on `fill` once and have only one `geom_col`. Hence the `fill` legend's key glyph is a rectangle.
- In your second plot you add a `geom_point` where you map on the `color` aes, i.e. here the `fill` legend still shows only key glyph for `geom_col` but now you get a `color` legend too which uses the key glyph for the `geom_point` aka a dot.
- In the third plot you also map on the `fill` aes in `geom_point`, which adds the `geom_point`'s key glyph aka the dot to the `fill` legend.

And to make clear that this has nothing to do with mapping on the `color` aes here is a more minimal reprex:

```r
library(ggplot2) # ggplot2_3.4.2

data.frame(x = 1, y = 2) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = "a")) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = .5) ->
p

p +
  geom_point(aes(fill = "a"))
```

[image]